# How to read text from command prompt using a .bat

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to get into windows batch files and programming in general, I messed around with an example I found online and made a batch file that creates another batch file (for the sake of learning)

But I now want to enable typing into a command prompt, I have a crude solution to this where I make a batch file, then create another batch file and start that file using the orignal .bat (don't worry, code is below, will make sense.)

Basically if you type 1, I want to do something in the batch, I know that I need to first do an if, but it's trying to get the text entered in the command line that I'm struggling with....  Any help would be great!

```
@echo off
  if exist CommandTest.bat ( 
    echo File already exists...
  pause
) else (
    echo CommandTest.bat does not exist. Creating the file...
   timeout /t 3 /NOBREAK>nul
    echo Please wait while your file loads...
         echo @echo off >CommandTest.bat
         echo color 0a >>CommandTest.bat
         echo echo Line number 1 >>CommandTest.bat
         echo timeout /t 3 /NOBREAK>nul >>CommandTest.bat
         echo echo Line number 2 >>CommandTest.bat
         echo timeout /t 3 /NOBREAK>nul >>CommandTest.bat
         echo echo Line number 3 >>CommandTest.bat
         echo timeout /t 3 /NOBREAK>nul >>CommandTest.bat
         echo echo Line number 4 >>CommandTest.bat
         echo timeout /t 3 /NOBREAK>nul >>CommandTest.bat
    timeout /t 2 /NOBREAK>nul
 start CommandTest.bat
 timeout /t 5 /NOBREAK>nul
 )
```

I am basically trying to redesign it to be user interactive...

Comment: check `set /p` ->https://ss64.com/nt/set.html. What do you mean by read by console though.Why you need a new file when you can start the bat itself and with an argument to point out which subroutine you want to execute.

Comment: also [choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) may be a good alternative, if the input is a single keystroke (like `press 1 to do x, press 2 to do y`)

Comment: Okay, I will try explain again, this batch is an example, to show I am at least trying, I am new to batch files and the only languages I done was html and a very small amount of lua (mainly maths) so I am easily confused with windows batch files since this is the first time I am trying something likes this.  

I am trying to make a batch, allow a user to choose options, eg, 1 and 2.

I am then trying to trigger an if to start a file when the user chooses one of these options, hope this explains it better. :)

Comment: To print a redirector as a literal, use `^>` (like in `echo...>nul...>>filename` - use `echo..^>nul...>>filename`). also `(echo this\necho that\necho something else)>filename` will create a new file with the accumulation of the `echo` statements (you need to replace `\n` with a newline - `\n` literally will not work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, `choice` is the right choice for you:

```
@echo off
echo 1 - do something
echo 2 - do something else
echo 3 - do nothing
choice /c 123 /m "take your choice "
if %errorlevel% == 1 echo let's do something
if %errorlevel% == 2 goto :other
if %errorlevel% == 3 echo let's do nothing
pause
goto :eof

:other 
echo let's do something else
echo something else ...
pause
```

Comment: Thanks so much :) I just have one final question....  Is there a way to return to your terminal when you choose a choice?  I say this because I noticed it closes straight after.

Comment: How do you start it? With a double-click with your mouse? Yes, of course it exits when it is finished. You can add a `pause` or `timeout` command.

Comment: One more problem, it starts both files...  I tried putting them as they were, should I use goto instead?

Comment: @KieranBrown then your order is incorrect. show your new edited code. then we can see.

Comment: CHOICE /C AB /N /T 10 /D A /M "A starts the file again, B deletes this file."
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 start Create_Stuff.bat
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 start Delete_Stuff.bat this is a comment, but you get the idea, on different lines (this is the CREATED batch file after I run the file to create it. :)

Comment: There is a reason, why I used `%errorlevel%` instead of just `errorlevel`: `if errorlevel 2` is in reality `if errorlevel is two or higher`